# how to sync frames while calculating vmaf score using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have one source video and encoder version of that source. Now I need to find vmaf score. However I read that to ensure right vmaf score, it is important that both source and encoded videos are in frame sync. Can you please advise how can i do that using filters on decoded streams in ffmpeg. I

I have command like below

```
ffmpeg2 -i 11sec_encoded_720p_200k.mp4 -i 11sec_original_1080p.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080:flags=bicubic[main]; [main][1:v]libvmaf=model_path=vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl:psnr=1:ssim=1:ms_ssim=1:log_fmt=json:log_path=720p_200k.json" -report -f null -
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trim` filter to handle the `<offset>` between your inputs videos, i. e.,

- If the first frame of `11sec_encoded_720p_200k.mp4` (*Distorted*) is ahead in comparison with `11sec_original_1080p.mxf` (*Reference*), apply `trim` to the *Reference* by specifying the `<offset>` value. The  `<offset>` should be the value in seconds on the *Reference Video* where its frame match with the first frame of the *Distorted* one (see command the image below):

```
ffmpeg2 -i 11sec_encoded_720p_200k.mp4 -i 11sec_original_1080p.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080:flags=bicubic[main];[1:v]trim=start=<you offset> [ref];[main][ref]libvmaf=model_path=vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl:psnr=1:ssim=1:ms_ssim=1:log_fmt=json:log_path=720p_200k.json" -report -f null -
```

[image: image1]

- Otherwise, if `11sec_original_1080p.mxf` (*Reference*) is ahead in regards with `11sec_encoded_720p_200k.mp4` (*Distorted*), apply `trim` to the *Distorted* (See command image below):

```
ffmpeg2 -i 11sec_encoded_720p_200k.mp4 -i 11sec_original_1080p.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=<you offset> [main0];[main0]scale=1920x1080:flags=bicubic[main];[main][1:v]libvmaf=model_path=vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl:psnr=1:ssim=1:ms_ssim=1:log_fmt=json:log_path=720p_200k.json" -report -f null -
```

[image]

The above examples consider that you already know the right offset, if it is not the case, you need to compute it. This computation could be done using a sample of the *Distorted* video and sliding it frame-by-frame (forward and backward) in order to look up the best PSNR in regard to the `Reference`. Once the best PSNR is found, the amount of time slided is the offset needed to get the frames synced. Here, you can find a python script that already deal with this issues: https://github.com/gdavila/easyVmaf